# How can I access my JSON object?

Tags: swift, xcode, nsmutabledictionary, nsjsonserialization

I'm getting a JSON object returned from a URL request and I've converted it using the code below

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            self.alertView("Error - " + error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            do {
                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    for item in json {
                        if (item as? (String, AnyObject)) != nil {
                           //Get values here
```

This works but the value of item is displayed below. I've tried several methods but I can't get the values for the Dictionary with 23 key/value pairs.

[image]

The variable item is declared as (String, AnyObject). How can I retreive these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Dictionary with 23 key/value pairs* is the value for key `result`

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
   if let result = json["result"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
      for (key, value) in result {
          print(key, value)
      }
   } 
}
```